# sublime text key bindings : is there any way to navigate 'back' and 'forward'

Tags: sublimetext, key-bindings

in eclipse or vs or si, I can type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to navigate to last view(back) or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to next view(forward), is there any keyboard shortcut or plugin to do this in sublime text.
i tried searching in package control and nothing seems related

Comment: I think you can get something like this with a view port or location stack

Answer (score 1):

You can define that behavior in the user key bindings.

```
Preferences -> Key Bindings - User
```

And then define there the combination of keys that you want. E.g. In this case, those commands would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+6"], "command": "next_view" },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+4"], "command": "prev_view" }
]
```

Comment: sorry, it's not what i asked. for example, i'm reading ln123 which is a=1; then i jump to a's define line to see what a is, then **i want to jump back to keep reading**,what should i do now

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I wished to do the same. I found that such navigation can be configured in Sublime Text 3 via user key bindings:

```
Preferences -> Key Bindings - User
```

Include these { braced lines } in the [ array ]:

```
[
  { "keys": ["alt+left"], "command": "jump_back" },
  { "keys": ["alt+right"], "command": "jump_forward" }
]
```

(For earlier versions of Sublime, there's an extension https://github.com/timjrobinson/SublimeNavigationHistory)